# Hooking a java application crashes/freezes the application

Tags: c++, hook

I just implemented a system-wide hook; it hooks into 32-bit processes and reverses their text (eg. hooks into textpad and reverses menu text etc., just to get some basic hooking going). I posted my code here:

[Having trouble with microsoft detours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624096/having-trouble-with-microsoft-detours/8634206#8634206)

It works fine for textpad, chrome etc., but when I try to use it on the one program I really need, a java application, the application freezes. The program itself appears unaffected; no strange error codes or anything. It's the application (which is my broker's trading platform) that freezes. It's a .jnlp file that is launched via the java web-starter (which subsequently loads up the trading platform). It launches as a 32-bit process usng jre6.

I am running Windows 7 64-bit, Visual Studio 10.0, Detours 3.0. This is pretty unfamiliar territory for me; not sure how to proceed or how to debug this issue. I'm not married to the approach I used; if I could circumvent this issue with a different kind of hook I would gladly use that. Any idea how I can solve/debug this issue? Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: Tried this on Intellij (a java IDE) and it freezes that too. I wondered if maybe it was just the fact that these applications load a ton of processes so maybe that was mucking things up, but tried it on Adobe Photoshop Elements (also loads a ton of processes) and it worked fine on that. So still stuck.

Answer (score 1):

When you hook a process,  you need to use 32 bit hook to hook a 32 bit process.  Since you use VS 2010 64 bit,  Have you set up your solution to generate a 32 bit hook?

Your target is a Java application.  You may want to try the Java Accessibility to attch to the process and then use reflection to get the text and reverse it.

Good luck