# When is WindowProc called?

Tags: c#, windows, pinvoke

In my C# program using P/Invoke I change the procedure address for my window.
So I can react to windows messages I'm interested in.

But when is the procedure called by the System?
I have Lists that I manipulate both in my custom procedure, and in the rest of my code.
How does the system decide when it can or can't call the procedure, 
and is there a chance that data can be corrupted?

e.g.

I add entries to a list in my procedure.

I read-through the list and process the entries in another part of my code.

Before I manage to clear list, the procedure takes over and adds more entries.

Return back to the other part of my code, the list is cleared and the new entries are discarded without being processed.

Comment: It doesn't matter when, you aren't in control of it, therefore you can't rely on it. Your other part of the code should manage all the operations on the list. Trap the message and pass it to the list controller.

Comment: Why are you hacking when you could use a supported mechanism?

Comment: @David I'm just overriding WindowProc so I can capture messages sent to my app window in order to handle user input (text and keys/mouse).

Comment: So why don't you do that with the supported mechanisms instead of messing with pinvoke?

Comment: As for when a window proc is called, you don't care about that. What you care about is that the window proc is always executed in the thread that created the window. So run you code that changes window proc in that thread and you'll  know that the window thread cannot be executing.

Comment: Ok, but as in the example i posted, my window proc stores message info in a container, while my main code acts on that same container. Isn't it possible that the system calls the proc at a bad time, and I lose/corrupt data?

Comment: @BobCoder: if you use the supported method of overriding WndProcs, and add your container code before calling the base implementation, you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: Ok, but I still would like to know how the system decides when to interrupt the flow of my program in order to send messages. Or is it the app itself that asks for messages?

Comment: In that case you can read the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be using p/invoke to do this, as it can interfere with the way Windows Forms (or WPF) manage the message pump.

If you must, you can try these approaches:
[Setting up Hook on Windows messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665579/setting-up-hook-on-windows-messages)

Or you can override WndProc in your main form class, which needs no further explanation.

Comment: There are a number of ways I can capture windows messages. What I don't know is when is the windows message sent and processed. I want to store the message data when it is sent, and then use it when it is convenient for my app (eg when its not busy doing something else). So I still need to know when it is that the Windows OS decides to send the message to my app.

Comment: @BobCoder: the app polls windows for messages in the message pump. That happens whenever all processing for the current message has taken place.

Comment: @siride That's the case for asynchronous messages. Synchronous ones are delivered in a different manner.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: ahh right, I forgot about the SendMessage case. Either way, it shouldn't affect BobCoder's program structure, as he will have to override WndProc and capture the messages there, regardless of their source.