# Disable editable WebBrowser control's save dialog C#

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

I hope you guys can help me out here.

I have an application written in C#, that uses a WebBrowser control to edit HTML files (marked with 2 on the screenshot), and here's the code that initializes it:

```
    htmlEditor.DocumentText = "";
    doc = htmlEditor.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
    doc.designMode = "On";
    htmlEditor.Url = new Uri(Properties.Main.Default.tempDir + "\\section-1.html");
```

I also have a listview control, that shows the list of HTML files(marked with 1 on the screenshot). Each time the user clicks on a list item, an event is triggered and the webbrowser control loads a different HTML file, and here's the code for that:

```
    private void sectionsTree_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, RadTreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        Sections.fileCheck();

        if (sectionsTree.SelectedNode != null)
        {
            emDataSet.dtSectionsDataTable sectionsDT = new emDataSet.dtSectionsDataTable();
            sectionsDT.ReadXml(Properties.Main.Default.tempDir + "\\sections.xml");

            for (int i = 0; i < sectionsDT.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (sectionsTree.SelectedNode.Text == sectionsDT.Rows[i][2].ToString())
                {
                    htmlEditor.Url = new Uri(Properties.Main.Default.tempDir + "\\" + sectionsDT.Rows[i][1].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now here comes my problem: because the HTML page loaded in the webbrowser control is editable, each time I select a new item on the list (and before a new HTML file is loaded) a Save dialog appears (marked with 3 on the screenshot). I have my own code to save the changed HTML file, triggered by the "changing" event and it would be great if there would be somehow a solution to bypass, suppress, skip, or just simply hide this Save dialog, so the user won't need to click it every time he wants to go to another file. Here's the changing event:

```
    private void sectionsTree_SelectedNodeChanging(object sender, RadTreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Sections.fileCheck();

        if (sectionsTree.SelectedNode != null)
        {
            emDataSet.dtSectionsDataTable sectionsDT = new emDataSet.dtSectionsDataTable();
            sectionsDT.ReadXml(Properties.Main.Default.tempDir + "\\sections.xml");

            for (int i = 0; i < sectionsDT.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (sectionsTree.SelectedNode.Text == sectionsDT.Rows[i][2].ToString())
                {
                    File.WriteAllText(Properties.Main.Default.tempDir + "\\" + sectionsDT.Rows[i][1].ToString(), htmlEditor.DocumentText);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My opinion is that the above codes are okay, and have nothing to do with my problem, because, my understanding is that the problem comes from a built-in feature of the WebBrowser control, however, just maybe, it could be a solution to intercept the WebBrowser control just before it checks if the file has been changed or not, and save it, so when it's checked it won't trigger the Save dialog, but I haven't figured out how to do that.

[image]

I'm looking forward to all your answers, and feel free to ask anything.

Thanks,
Aemeth

Answer (score 0):

you may use this

WebBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand(“Refresh”, False, “”)

found at this http://www.spheregen.com/disable-save-dialog-in-webbrowser-editing/

Hope to work for you

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this recently and never had success using the `Document.ExecCommand("Refresh")` as described.

What has worked for me is to use Windows API calls to send the `WM_CLOSE` message to the dialog, allowing me to suppress the dialog but still handle the file saving/reloading in the background.

SO answer: [Setting up Hook on Windows messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665579/setting-up-hook-on-windows-messages) was helpful in setting everything up, but the general gist of it was to obtain the dialog class (`#32770`), then make sure that the title of the dialog contained my temporary filename, then obtain the handle to that dialog and send it `WM_CLOSE`.

The body of my delegate function for `SetWinEventHook` is as follows, hopefully this is of some help.

```
GetClassName(hWnd, ClassName, ClassName.Capacity);
GetWindowText(hWnd, DialogTitle, DialogTitle.Capacity);
DialogHandle = FindWindow(DIALOG_CLASS, DialogTitle.ToString());

if (ClassName.ToString() == DIALOG_CLASS && DialogTitle.ToString().Contains(TempFilename))
{
     ReturnValue = SendMessage(DialogHandle, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

`ClassName` and `DialogTitle` are of `StringBuilder` type, `ReturnValue` and `DialogHandle` are of `IntPtr` type. `TempFilename` is a string containing a tempfile name generated by `Path.GetTempFileName()`

You'll need API calls to `SetWinEventHook`, `UnhookWinEvent`, `GetClassName`, `GetWindowText`, `FindWindow`, and `SendMessage` - PInvoke.net should be able to help with those. You'll also need a few constants setting up, again - PInvoke can help.

It's not the most elegant solution, but it works!

Edited to add - if you want to actually interact with the dialog, rather than just arbitrarily close it, you can use the code found at PInvoke here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumchildwindows then, pass `DialogHandle` in the code above to the `GetChildWindows()` function and iterate through the list of returned `IntPtr` objects, calling `GetWindowText()` on each item until you find a value that matches either "`&Yes`" (for the Yes button), "`&No`" (for the No button) or "`Cancel`" (for the cancel button).

Once you have the handle of the button, send it the `BM_CLICK` message (0x00F5) and you can suppress the dialog without losing the functionality of it.

As you're only iterating through the targeted dialog rather than every window, this is a pretty fast operation (took 2ms when tested) so shouldn't cause any slowdowns.

The code changes to the following:

```
GetClassName(hWnd, ClassName, ClassName.Capacity);
GetWindowText(hWnd, DialogTitle, DialogTitle.Capacity);
DialogHandle = FindWindow(DIALOG_CLASS, DialogTitle.ToString());

if (ClassName.ToString() == DIALOG_CLASS && DialogTitle.ToString().Contains(TempFilename))
{
    foreach (IntPtr ChildWindow in GetChildWindows(hWnd))
    {
        StringBuilder ChildCaption = new StringBuilder(100);
        GetWindowText(ChildWindow, ChildCaption, ChildCaption.Capacity);
        if (ChildCaption.ToString() == @"&Yes")
        {
            SendMessage(ChildWindow, BM_CLICK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
}
```